# GestureDetector ontap functionality on invisible space

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I am pretty new to flutter so excuse my noobish question but how do I expand the GestureDetector to the invisible space, so even if the user clicks on the highlighted area it registers and executes the ontap function?

[image: Screen]

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => BusinessPage(
                    business: business,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04,
                  ),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.028,
                    child: false
                        ? Text(
                            "AS",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.orange.shade800,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          )
                        : ClipOval(
                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                            child: Image.asset(
                              business.logo,
                              height:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.0545,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  business.name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.022,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: I am assuming you are working with some sort of list widget to render the components (probably in a column as well). You will need to wrap that column with the GestureDetector.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/58295509/6576315 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i think its better to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725308/flutter-inkwell-vs-gesturedetector-what-is-the-difference) about InkWell vs GestureDetector and what is the differences,

in your case i think better solution is [ListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html), just follow [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/listtile-widget-in-flutter/) to know more

but if you like this way, You need wrap your `Row` with [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) like this:

```
InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => BusinessPage(
                          business: business,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04,
                        ),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.028,
                          child: false
                              ? Text(
                                  "AS",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.orange.shade800,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                )
                              : ClipOval(
                                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    business.logo,
                                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                        0.0545,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

now just `Row` is clickable not any widget outside the `Row`

Comment: Replacing GestureDetector with Inkwell worked for me like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can add mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, property to Row or you can use ListTile instead

```
ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => BusinessPage(
                    business: business,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.028,
              child: false
                  ? Text(
                      "AS",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.orange.shade800,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    )
                  : ClipOval(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        business.logo,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.0545,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
            ),
            title: Text(
              business.name,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.022,
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).